# How to quickly extract archives on android?

Tags: zip

After spending a few hours on annoying file management apps and the various archival apps. I can't find a quick way to do this. Most of these are built like users are supposed to use them for the PC. The quick PC extraction of Right Click "Extract All / Here" is pipe dream on android.

How can i go about to do this?
Can I find or force an application to extract everything it finds at a certain location and extract it where it is.

I looked for some solution that automatically extracts archives upon download, but thats convoluted even on PC (but at least doable - do a command line and if you want trigger it by a folder monitor change). Couldn't make any headway on android for sure.

How would you go about easing your time with archives on android. Dumping them all in one place is fine by me so long as I don't have to go through annoying managers for every single archive i get.

Comment: You didn't mention which archive formats you are talking about. Give MiXplorer a try, very handy. Supports 7z, zip, tar and may be others too, with or without encryption and compression.

Comment: Try ZArchiver, if you haven't tried it yet. I guess it comes with the features you need.